# Ubuntu 22.04 Crashing both regularly & randomly. What can I disable/configure so this stops?

Tags: keyboard, mouse, 22.04, freeze, crash

> HP Pavilion-dm4-1165dx Linux kernel: 5.15.0-46-generic #49-Ubuntu SMP  x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux 8Gb RAM 1T HDD

I've had major issues.  Taken days to rectify my HP Pavilion dm4 laptop multi boot (with perfectly working Win 7).

After ripping out the /boot & /root partitions and starting again (with a saved & protected /home partition)

I'm asking, because if anything happens again - what should I do to spot fix the problem(s) instead of having to go nuclear and tear everything out & starting again.

Main visible issues:
-Crashing mid boot
-Freezing up the use of keyboard and mouse either at login or about...

[as I was writing that - the keyboard, cursor, and mouse locked up.  No secret key-combo out there can break it and bring the system back as it was. At least now since this latest 22.04 reinstall - the auto-restart upon crash brings it back.]

1-2 minutes into a full stable load-up and login. [*Just happened again]

Want to post this question for some prelim suggestions [crash] [crash]

Posting this from the machine in question using latest Fire Fox - keeps crashing

Will add more details from another machine.  Please let me know what info you need.

Comment: It seems like you are asking "*How do I troubleshoot this freeze/crash problem?*" This kind of troubleshooting requires patience. Try an Ubuntu LiveUSB's "Try Ubuntu" environment. Does it freeze/crash the same ways and with the same frequency that your installed Ubuntu system freezes/crashes?